# Google Analytics Dashboard for Different Sites

Tags: google-analytics

I have a small multitenant application and I want to use google analytics to track the different minitenants. Tutorials on this topic seem to be pretty scarce, but I was wondering how I would go about 
1) Rendering the dashboard for each 'site'
2) Allowing the creation of new sites for google analytic 'sites' automatically.
Using a 'global' Google account.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building dashboards to report on the analytics of your various sites/properties I would recommend using the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/?hl=en) to get started quickly. But since you stated you are interested in also managing [Google Analytics properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtWebpropertyGuide) programmatically. It might be useful go through the quick start guide for the language and application type of your choice. [Python Service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-java) or a [PHP Web App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-php), the list goes on.

But if you need to actually provision new accounts for each end user there is also the [Google Analytics Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/?hl=en). There are restrictions on who is allowed to use that API, namely you need to be [AdWords Channel Partner](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/?hl=en#access).